# Procjess JSON of unknown Formats

Tags: javascript, json, properties

a Services provides the following Information via JSON

```
{"errors":{"subject":"foobar"}}
```

and further alements in this errors array

OR

```
{"ok":{"subject":"foobarfoobar"}}
```

and further alements in this ok array array

So always either of the two is present, not both at once. Any as one is not present I always get an access error as one the proeprties is of course not existing

And I completely fail how to process this result. I always get "can not ... of undefined":

Currenlty I have:

```
if (data[0].hasOwnProperty("status")) {
        alert('ddd');
}
```

What is the correct way to test, if either errors or ok is provided?

**UPDATE**
blex is right: But on the serverside is use:
    `echo json_encode( array('errors' => $result['errors']) );`
Doesnt this mean I that errors is already the first element of an array? Why is this seen as an object propety?

**SOLUTION/LEARNING:**
Beware of PHP! As stated above `echo json_encode( array('errors' => $result['errors']) );` does NOT lead to encoding this as an JSON Array. What I missunderstood and oversaw was, that `{` is the Format/Notation for Objects NOT for Arrays. So to be an array it would have to be `[` . **So in the End PHP does encode Associative  Arrays as normal Object Properties not as arrays. That was my wrong assumption**

Comment: There is no `data[0]`, since `data` is an object with properties, not an array. Use  `data.hasOwnProperty("ok")` or `data.hasOwnProperty("errors")`

Comment: Thanks! But the JSON starts with {, doesnt this mean errors/ok is also seen as an array element itself? And on the serverside I indeed use an array to encode the errors/ok...So I thought I have to access like an array. You can write this in an answer and you will get the "Problem solved tick"

Comment: JSON are not arrays, so you cannot use data[0] to access a property, but you can do data['ok'] to access properties. you could try `data[ok] !== undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = { "errors": { "subject": "foobar" } };
    //var x = { "ok": { "subject": "foobarfoobar" } };
    if (x.errors) {

    } else if (x.ok) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're already on the right track. hasOwnProperty is the right way to check for the existence of these keys.

I'm not sure what language you're using, but it seems like json_encode is converting your array to a single object, then putting that object under the errors key.

One last thing, you should probably look into using HTTP response codes. If you can return a 200 OK for the okay scenario, and a 400 or 500 level code for your error, then you'll be able to use better methods of determining how to process these situation. jQuery.ajax has the ability to put two handlers in place, one for success and one for failure, for instance.

Comment: Just wanted to say thankyou! I am sorry I am not able to give to upvotes/ticks. But I  really appreciate your help! Wish you all the best! Tthanks!